# How can I make regex detect backspace or delete button inside a onChange property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, next.js

Hey I have an input field. using react at the moment the input field is for an expiry date for bank card

I am using regex to restrict the input field to only accept numbers and a dash `-`. Inserting the dash after the length of input text reaches 4 by doing this:

```
        let expiryTime = e.target.value;
        if (e.target.value.length === 4) {
            expiryTime += "-";
        }
```

But I have a problem when I try to delete the the characters i cant delete past 4th character because of the above statement

the output I was looking for was (YYYY-MM). here is my function using react for this:

```
    const handleExpiryDate = (e) => {
        // this regex is forcing the user to only have numbers or a dash
        const reg = new RegExp(/^[\d-]*$/g)
        if (!reg.test(e.target.value)) {
            return;
        }
        // cant delete past 4 because of this condition I still want to auto input the dash once a user types 4 numbers for the YYYY then dash MM
        let expiryTime = e.target.value;
        if (e.target.value.length === 4) {
            expiryTime += "-";
        }
        setExpiryDate(expiryTime);
    }
```

How can I solve it? is there a regex i can use to detect backspace or delete was pushed, or how can incopurate such regex into my regex condition like the `\b`?

```
// here is the element

                            <input 
                                className={styles.left_inputs} 
                                type="text" 
                                name="expiry_date" 
                                placeholder="Expiration date (YYYY-MM)" 
                                maxLength="7"
                                onChange={handleExpiryDate}
                                value={expiryDate}
                            />
```

Comment: just store the value as a flat string and format it when you assign the value, or strip the `-` out before you format it `let expiryTime = e.target.value.replace('-', '');`.

Comment: Here's a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-butterfly-pk0ef7?file=/src/App.js) (though your regex isn't quite right as it allows `1234-5-`)

Comment: I made the regex more explicit in the sample `/^\d{0,4}-?\d{0,2}$/`

Comment: i see that thanks for the new explicit regex. I missed to check the second dash in the end